# Store binary pattern match in a variable

Tags: elixir

I have a function that matches against some binary value:

```
  def parse(<<timestamp::binary-size(4)>>) do
    IO.inspect timestamp
  end
```

Unfortunately, my real "pattern" is MUCH longer than this. Would it be possible to store that pattern and match on it later?

```
@pattern <<timestamp::binary-size(4)>>
def parse(@pattern) do
  IO.inspect timestamp
end
```

Obviously, this doesn't work as I've written. And, no matter what I do with `quote` and `unquote` I can't seem to get this to work.

Comment: def parse(@pattern=value) do

Comment: That does not work, especially as the only change. Do you have more context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot store the pattern in a variable, but you can create a macro:

```
defmodule A do
  defmacro pattern do
    quote do
      <<var!(timestamp)::binary-size(4)>>
    end
  end

  def parse(pattern()) do
    IO.inspect timestamp
  end
end

A.parse("abcd")
A.parse("abcde")
```

Output:

```
"abcd"
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in A.parse/1
    a.exs:8: A.parse("abcde")
    (elixir) lib/code.ex:370: Code.require_file/2
```

Note that I had to use `var!(timestamp)` in the pattern. This is to disable Elixir's Macro Hygiene feature so that you can access that variable with the same name in the caller. You'll have to add `var!()` around each variable name in the pattern.

Edit: You can store a quoted pattern in a module attribute and then unquote it in the function argument:

```
defmodule A do
  @pattern quote do: <<var!(timestamp)::binary-size(4)>>
  def parse(unquote(@pattern)) do
    IO.inspect timestamp
  end
end
```

The output is identical to the macro code above.

Comment: This does work for me. But, I'm not sure why a macro works for quote, but `@pattern` doesn't. Still wrapping my head around that.

Maybe because `quote` doesn't really do the same thing outside of a macro?

Comment: I found a way to do this with patterns with quote/unquote and added it to my answer @TonyPitale.

Comment: That's it, what I was missing from my `quote`/`unquote` usage (mentioned briefly in the original question) was the use of `var!`. Bingo! Thanks @Dogbert.